# Can't insert animated smileys in richtextbox in my windows chat app in c#.net

Tags: c#, winforms, chat, gif, animated

Can't insert animated smileys  in my chat app, which is a windows application in c#. I was pasting directly images of smileys in my richtextbox, everything worked fine as long as they were non animated, but now I require animated smileys is there any way available??? I searched and found about using web control instead of rich textbox, but if possible i want to do it using richtextbox... please help me if you know the solution..!!!

I am using this code to insert static(non animated) smileys,it would be great if it could be modified to allow animated smiles too..

```
PictureBox p = sender as PictureBox;
p.Size = new Size(20, 20);
p.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;
Clipboard.SetImage(p.Image);
t_msg.Paste();
```

Answer (score 1):

The `System.Windows.Controls.RichTextBox` is not capable of displaying animated GIFs. You will need to take a different Control.

There are plenty of third-party controls available on the web. A quick google resulted the [TRichTextBox](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/134358/TRichTextBox-A-universal-RichTextBox-which-can-dis) which seems to do the job.

Comment: Thank you!! i tried it..but it is adding it as a picturebox,,as i searched earliear..but is it possible to copy this richtextbox completely with it's pictureboxes to another richtextbox as it is..if yes then how?and another query is,is it possible to save this richtextbox completely with it's added pictureboxes to database?if yes than how?because my chat app requires both of these..